# Kanji combinations

Tags: kanji, kana

Originally, i had thought that you could only put an onyomi and an onyomi together to form a word and use kunyomi with hiragana..that was all i knew about using kanji until i asked someone and they told me that you can use kun and on together and on and kana together. Is this true?I need a second answer, please. Can you use kun and kun together too? Thanks.

Comment: This has been explained multiple times. https://japanese.stackexchange.com/search?q=%E9%87%8D%E7%AE%B1%E8%AA%AD%E3%81%BF

Comment: Basically any combo you can think of exists in some form.